# Unable to set CSS on multiple class applied to AJAX

Tags: java, css, ajax, jsf, richfaces

I'm using richfaces in order to get some quick AJAX widget but I'm having trouble setting CSS parameter over it.

[image: HTML code]

As you can see the generated code has the following class name : "rf-ds rpds".
However applying style to ".rf-ds" or ".rpds' does not do anything.

```
.rpds{
    width:100%; 
}
```

Any idea why?
Thanks

Comment: I think you have to do this using Javascript after the ajax call completed.

Answer (score 1):

It is most probable that your style is overridden elsewhere, you can check it by putting `!important`:

```
.rpds{
    width:100% !important; 
}
```

You need to figure out what is overriding it  .

Comment: important allow me to expand a white band but at least my css is not being ignored now.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you cannot apply CSS over a richfaces' datascroller.

The good way to do it is to reRender your datatable according to your datascroller or the opposite.

JSF 2.0 code :

```
    <h:form id="productSearchForm" >
        <rich:dataTable id="listeProduits" rows="3" value="#{rpb.myDataList}" var="liste"  reRender="scroller" >
            <f:facet name="header">
                <rich:columnGroup >
                    <h:column><h:outputText value="Gamme" /></h:column>
                    <h:column><h:outputText value="Famille" /></h:column>
                    <h:column><h:outputText value="Produit" /></h:column>
                </rich:columnGroup>
            </f:facet>
                <h:column><h:outputText value="#{liste.gamme}" /></h:column>
                <h:column><h:outputText value="#{liste.famille}" /></h:column>
                <h:column><h:outputText value="#{liste.nom}" /></h:column>
            <f:facet name="footer">
                <rich:dataScroller id="scroller" for="listeProduits" maxPages="10" />
            </f:facet>
        </rich:dataTable>
    </h:form>
```

in this case the datatable is reRendered (redrawed) to the datascroller size.